# No poller has been defined for channel Adapter

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, sftp, channel

I am using one inbound channel for downloading files & then other outbound channel to upload files & i do not need any poller but dont know why i am getting this exception. Can someone please help me out in this issue. I am using spring 4.0.6 Integration and spring core 4.0.6.

Logtrace:

```
    Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sftpInboundAdapter': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No poller has been defined for channel-adapter 'sftpInboundAdapter', and no default poller is available within the context.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:684)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.canaldigital.tsi.bank.config.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:35)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No poller has been defined for channel-adapter 'sftpInboundAdapter', and no default poller is available within the context.
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:112)
    at org.springframework.integration.config.SourcePollingChannelAdapterFactoryBean.initializeAdapter(SourcePollingChannelAdapterFactoryBean.java:157)
    at org.springframework.integration.config.SourcePollingChannelAdapterFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(SourcePollingChannelAdapterFactoryBean.java:115)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1549)
```

ApplicationConfig.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
    xmlns:int-sftp="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/sftp"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/task 
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-4.0.xsd                          
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration   
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/sftp
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/sftp/spring-integration-sftp.xsd">                    

    <bean id="sftpSessionFactory" class="org.springframework.integration.file.remote.session.CachingSessionFactory">
        <constructor-arg ref="defaultSftpSessionFactory" />
    </bean>

 <int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter id="sftpInboundAdapter"
            session-factory="sftpSessionFactory"
            channel="requestSFTPSEDEVChannel"
            filename-pattern="*.*"
            remote-directory="/home/oracle/IBSTOBANK/Test/Incoming/"
            preserve-timestamp="true"
            local-directory="C:/Working_Directory/temp/SE-DEV/"
            auto-create-local-directory="true"
            temporary-file-suffix=".writing"
            delete-remote-files="true">
    <!-- <int:poller fixed-rate="1000"/> -->
</int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter> 

     <int-sftp:outbound-channel-adapter id="sftpOutboundAdapter"
            session-factory="sftpSessionFactory"
            channel="requestOutBoundChannel"
            remote-directory="/home/oracle/IBSTOBANK/Test/Outgoing/">       
</int-sftp:outbound-channel-adapter>



    <int:channel id="requestSFTPSEDEVChannel">
    </int:channel>

    <int:channel id="requestOutBoundChannel">
    </int:channel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, looks like you must come back to the [theory](http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/PollingConsumer.html) and understand difference between `polling` and `event-listening`.

From other side you should agree that SFTP is some kind of remote file system and there is really no any other way to download new files from there, unless **polling**. The rule is applied for the JDBC, when we'd like to read new records from the table and so on.

So, since we agreed that `<int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter>` is exactly `Polling Consumer`, we must declare `<poller>`, implicitly or like a `global` one.

That's from the side of the existing design and your config on the matter.

From other side let us know what you mean with:

> i do not need any poller

How are you going to download files from the SFTP?
Yes, actually `<int-sftp:outbound-gateway>` can do the stuff for you, but that is a bit different story...

Comment: Ah my Bad ... I think i should edit this question. Yeah you are right Inbound must have poller.

Comment: Inbound channel is working perfect but when it comes to outbound-channel-adapter it thorws an exception:     Dispatcher has no subscribers.

Comment: That's correct, too. Your inbound adapter uses `requestSFTPSEDEVChannel` and I really don't see any subscriber for that one. Your outbound adapter uses different channel - `requestOutBoundChannel`. That is your "hell". Sorry, I can't help to fix your inattention...